# Unable to get a specific Cell value from a Table

Tags: vba, vb.net, excel, vsto

I need to port some `VBA` code to a `VB.Net` addon, but I can't get a particular cell value from my Table.

I am able to change `Range(2,2)` to `"Test"` but `table.Range(2, 2).ToString` gives `System.__ComObject` as Value.

[image: This is Image of my table]

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) _
Handles Button1.Click

    Dim table As Excel.ListObject
    table = Globals.wsTables.ListObjects("vehicleDefinations")
    table.Range(2, 2) = "Test"

    Dim file As New System.IO.StreamWriter _
    ("C:\Users\Ryzen2600x\Downloads\Debug.txt", False)
    file.WriteLine(table.Range(2, 2).ToString)
    file.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing the code to `file.WriteLine(table.Range(2, 2).Value2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use .Range to retrieve the value. Instead try to use

table.DataBodyRange.Cells(2, 2)

or

[MyTable].Cells(2,2)

Comment: He's using `ListObject().Range` property, not `Application.Range`, that is a perfectly valid way to reference to table data...

Comment: To add to that, `table.DataBodyRange.Cells(2,2)` (and so will the other) will result in an error, as this expression expects `=` for Value assignment!

Comment: it gives me System.__ComObject as output,

Comment: file.WriteLine(table.DataBodyRange.Range("B1").Value) is working but i want it in (1,1) format to put it in loop

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `.Value`

```
file.WriteLine(table.Range(2, 2).Value.ToString)
```

Comment: adding .value giving me syntax error "Option Strict On disallows late binding"

Answer (score 0):

Please reference this code:

```
private void ListObject_Range()
{
   Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject list1 = this.Controls.AddListObject(this.Range["A1", "C4"], "list1");
   MessageBox.Show("The list object contains " + list1.Range.Cells.Count.ToString() + " cells.");
}
```

More informaiton, please see

[ListObject.Range Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.range.aspx)

Help it helps you.

Thanks,
Yuki